# error: long found, whereas array required

Tags: java

What is wrong with my code? My output has to be the sum of all long elements in the second row of 'ar'.

```
public class Solution {
    // Complete the aVeryBigSum function below.
    static long aVeryBigSum(long[] ar) {
    long size = ar[0];
    long resultHere = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < size){

        resultHere += ar[1][i];
        i++;
    }
    return resultHere;
}
```

I get this:
Solution.java:18: error: array required, but long found
            resultHere += ar[1][i];
                               ^
refer: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/a-very-big-sum/
for problem

Comment: what type is `ar` ? and how do you access an element from a **single** dimensional array ? look closer at `ar[1][i];`

Comment: array is a 2d long array, the first line is the size of the array, and second line in the list of long elements to be added

Comment: "array is a 2d long array,"... that's not what `long[] ar` says. you have 2 options. 1) change the declaration of the method parameter to a two-dimensional array 2) or accommodate the line `ar[1][i];`.

Comment: Further, consider using a `for` loop or an enhanced for loop, this is not a job for a `while` loop.

Comment: i misread the problem statement, thanks

Comment: btw all that code could potentially be reduced to --> `return LongStream.of(ar).sum();`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if you’re not here to talk about the code and instead make condescending remarks, I suggest you keep your comments to yourself :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson also im all about the learning part of hackerank, but I didn’t post to get learning tips

Answer (score 1):

Here `resultHere += ar[1][i];` you are trying to access a two-dimensional array and the `ar` array is only one dimensional.

One Dimensional array:

```
long[] oneDimensional = new long[10];
```

Two dimensional array:

```
long[][] twoDimensional = new long[10][10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Solution {
    // Complete the aVeryBigSum function below.
    static long aVeryBigSum(long[] ar) {
    long size = ar[0];
    long resultHere = 0;
    int i = 1;
      while (i < size){
        resultHere += ar[i];
        i++;
    }
    return resultHere;
}
```